# gulp-concat does not concat one of my files on heroku

Tags: angularjs, heroku, gulp

I'm using gulp to generate a config.js file for angular, then use another gulp task to concat all .js files together, the gulp tasks look like this:

```
gulp.task('config', function() {
    var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    gulp.src('public/config/' + environment + '.json')
        .pipe(ngConstant({
            name: 'app.config'
        }))
        .pipe(concat('public/js/config.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});

gulp.task('js', ['config'], function() {
    gulp.src('public/js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'));
});


gulp.task('default', ['config', 'js']);
```

If I run gulp locally, everything works file.

But when I push to heroku, using this post install script:

```
"postinstall": "bower install && gulp"
```

I can see gulp run successfully, after adding some debug, I can see the config.js file is even created correctly, but the generated app.js does not include config.js. Can anyone suggest what might be wrong here?

**UPDATE**: I found it works if I do `gulp config && gulp js` but not `gulp`, is this because gulp is async and config.js wasn't created when js job started to run? but i thought I have already specified the task dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: I'm not returning a stream from tasks, for example the config task should be like this:

```
gulp.task('config', function() {
    var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    var stream = gulp.src('public/config/' + environment + '.json')
        .pipe(ngConstant({
            name: 'app.config'
        }))
        .pipe(concat('public/js/config.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
    return stream; // THIS IS IMPORTANT!
});
```